# Flutter doctor proxy detection

Tags: flutter, dart-pub

I have been having endless proxy authentication problems when trying to run

```
flutter pub get
```

I have added the HTTP_PROXY, HTTPS_PROXY and NOPROXY variables to my system variables which did not work.

I then remove all the flutter required proxy variables and ran Flutter Doctor again, but even with all the variables removed it still shows

```
• HTTP_PROXY is set
• NO_PROXY is 127.0.0.1,localhost
• NO_PROXY contains 127.0.0.1
• NO_PROXY contains localhost
```

Is there a config that is being set when the **set http_proxy=host:port** is being set in cmd?

Comment: you solved this?

Comment: Yes, I ended up finding what the problem was. At work we have 2 different accounts, one with admin rights and your day-to-day account which does not. So when updating the environment variables with the admin account, they were not being applied to the global variables but rather only for the admin account, since all the programs and applications are linked to the day-to-day account they could not see those variables